Does OpenStack Nova Scheduler support a PCPU-based Weigher?
In our OpenStack environment, we exclusively use dedicated CPUs (PCPUs). All instances require dedicated physical cores, and shared CPUs (VCPUs) are not utilized.
We are running OpenStack Yoga (25.2.1). While Nova Scheduler correctly filters hosts based on PCPU usage, it appears that the weigher mechanism only considers VCPU usage. This creates a risk of PCPU workloads becoming concentrated on specific hosts, leading to potential resource contention.
Since Train, Placement has introduced dedicated_set and shared_set to manage resources for PCPU and VCPU allocation. However, Nova Scheduler's weigher seems to not reflect these updates. Below is a relevant log excerpt from our environment:
nova-scheduler 2024-12-03 10:25:09.313 11 DEBUG nova.weights [req-c5e144ed-f27a-4fa9-8682-e132c548ab01 b0b3f634c3d343a1912884e3d2a4add7 e71c3cd30f0643cb9019d1f9a87440de - default default] CPUWeigher: raw weights {('hqinventory15', 'hqinventory15'): 0, ('hqinventory14', 'hqinventory14'): 0} get_weighed_objects /var/lib/openstack/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nova/weights.py:136
nova-scheduler 2024-12-03 10:25:09.313 11 DEBUG nova.weights [req-c5e144ed-f27a-4fa9-8682-e132c548ab01 b0b3f634c3d343a1912884e3d2a4add7 e71c3cd30f0643cb9019d1f9a87440de - default default] CPUWeigher: normalized weights {('hqinventory15', 'hqinventory15'): 0, ('hqinventory14', 'hqinventory14'): 0} get_weighed_objects /var/lib/openstack/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nova/weights.py:148
nova-scheduler 2024-12-03 10:25:09.314 11 DEBUG nova.weights [req-c5e144ed-f27a-4fa9-8682-e132c548ab01 b0b3f634c3d343a1912884e3d2a4add7 e71c3cd30f0643cb9019d1f9a87440de - default default] CPUWeigher: score (multiplier * weight) {('hqinventory15', 'hqinventory15'): '1.0 * 0', ('hqinventory14', 'hqinventory14'): '1.0 * 0'} get_weighed_objects /var/lib/openstack/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nova/weights.py:166

We are using the following flavor configuration for our instances:
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                      | Value                                                                                |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled   | False                                                                                |
| OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral  | 0                                                                                    |
| access_project_ids         | None                                                                                 |
| description                | None                                                                                 |
| disk                       | 0                                                                                    |
| id                         | U.C1.8VCPU.16GB                                                                      |
| name                       | U.C1.8VCPU.16GB                                                                      |
| os-flavor-access:is_public | True                                                                                 |
| properties                 | hw:cpu_policy='dedicated', hw:cpu_sockets='1', hw:cpu_threads='2', hw:numa_nodes='1' |
| ram                        | 16384                                                                                |
| rxtx_factor                | 1.0                                                                                  |
| swap                       |                                                                                      |
| vcpus                      | 8                                                                                    |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

We have observed that the CPUWeigher assigns a raw weight of 0 to all hosts, regardless of their PCPU usage. This indicates that the weigher is not taking PCPU utilization into account. Based on Placement's ability to manage dedicated_set and shared_set, we expected Nova Scheduler to weigh hosts based on their PCPU usage for better load balancing.
We are seeking clarification on the following points:
Is it correct that Nova Scheduler does not natively support a PCPU-based weigher?
Has there been any community discussion, feature request, or blueprint for implementing this?
Are there any known workarounds or patches for distributing PCPU workloads more effectively in Nova Scheduler?
Since we only use PCPUs in our environment, we are looking for a way to distribute workloads based on PCPU usage effectively.
Thank you in advance for your insights!
